# cakephp 1.3 : how to omit virtual fields from a find query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, find, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to convert the output of a Model->find query into SQL to be input into a database completely separate from the current MySQL database being used by the cakePHP system. My problem is that I have several virtual fields in the models which are inevitably returned when performing a Model->find on the data. Clearly, I need to find and remove these virtual fields from the find if I am to convert the data into SQL, which will be used as input to an identical database as the original MySQL one. Is there a simple way to omit virtual fields? any way that this can be done in a version higher than 1.3 would also be very helpful.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either only define your virtual fiels at runtime. This is what I usually do.

```
$this->virtualFields['x'] = 'y';
// find query
```

But you can also limit the find fields

'fields' => array('all fields without the virtual fields')

This will also skip your virtual fields.
Usually you don't want to verbosely define all fields, though.

You can also unset all the virtual fields for the find() call:

```
$tmp = $this->virtualFields;
$this->virtualFields = array();
// find query
$this->virtualFields = $tmp;
```

Comment: What to do, if you need to remove the virtual-fields temporary on a JOINED (hasMany, belongsTo, habtm,...) model?